# How do test if a post is a custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, conditional-content, conditional-tags

I am looking for a way to test if a post is a custom post type. For example, in, say, the sidebar I can put in code like this:

```
 if ( is_single() ) {
     // Code here
 }
```

I want code testing for only a custom post type.

Answer (score 165, accepted):

Here you are: [`get_post_type()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_type) and then `if ( 'book' == get_post_type() ) ...` as per [Conditional Tags > A Post Type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags#A_Post_Type) in Codex.

Comment: [`is_singular()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_singular) is bit more compact [Conditional Tags > A Single Page, Single Post or Attachment](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags#A_Single_Page.2C_Single_Post_or_Attachment)

Comment: @Rarst This only apply to the single post template of a CPT. `get_post_type()` is the right way to go in a more broad approach. (eg: on a search page)

Comment: @amarinediary I think at the time the question was unclear if the interest is in checking main page-defining post or just _some_ post in an arbitrary loop. The appropriate way to express with template tag would vary accordingly. :)

Comment: is_singular()  - more fastes...  0.000001 sec.     get_post_type() - 0.000637 sec

Answer (score 194):

```
if ( is_singular( 'book' ) ) {
    // conditional content/code
}
```

The above is `true` when viewing a post of the custom post type: `book`.

```
if ( is_singular( array( 'newspaper', 'book' ) ) ) {
    //  conditional content/code
}
```

The above is `true` when viewing a post of the custom post types: `newspaper` or `book`.

These and more conditional tags [can be viewed here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags#A_Single_Page.2C_Single_Post_or_Attachment).

Answer (score 34):

To test if a post is *any* custom post type, fetch the list of all not built-in post types and test if the post’s type is in that list.

As a function:

```
/**
 * Check if a post is a custom post type.
 * @param  mixed $post Post object or ID
 * @return boolean
 */
function is_custom_post_type( $post = NULL )
{
    $all_custom_post_types = get_post_types( array ( '_builtin' => FALSE ) );

    // there are no custom post types
    if ( empty ( $all_custom_post_types ) )
        return FALSE;

    $custom_types      = array_keys( $all_custom_post_types );
    $current_post_type = get_post_type( $post );

    // could not detect current type
    if ( ! $current_post_type )
        return FALSE;

    return in_array( $current_post_type, $custom_types );
}
```

Usage:

```
if ( is_custom_post_type() )
    print 'This is a custom post type!';
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: any idea how to check the post type in the backend?

Comment: @evavienna This code works everywhere. You just need a post object.

Answer (score 30):

Add this to your `functions.php`, and you can have the functionality, inside or outside of the loop:

```
function is_post_type($type){
    global $wp_query;
    if($type == get_post_type($wp_query->post->ID)) 
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

So you can now use the following:

```
if (is_single() && is_post_type('post_type')){
    // Work magic
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very useful!
But it should be: if (is_single() && is_post_type('post_type')){ //work magic
} The closing bracket was missing....
Many greetings, Ethel

Comment: Has this stopped working for anyone else? I've used this for ages, but suddenly this stopped working for me. However, using the same method **without** global $wp_query always works: `if ( 'post-type' == get_post_type() ) {}`

Comment: is_post_type() is depreciated.

Comment: how do I get the slug from `get_post_type($wp_query->post->ID)` is it possible to do something like this `get_post_type($wp_query->post->SLUG)`

Answer (score 15):

If for any reason you already have access to the global variable $post, you can simply use

```
if ($post->post_type == "your desired post type") {
}
```

Answer (score 9):

If you want a wild card check for all your custom post types:

```
if( ! is_singular( array('page', 'attachment', 'post') ) ){
    // echo 'Imma custom post type!';
}
```

This way you don't need to know the name of your custom post. Also the code still work even if you change the name of your custom post later.

Answer (score 0):

To determine the $post_type easily inside a function, you need to call the global post var first, here is an example:

```
function the_views() {
global $post;

if ($post->post_type == "game") {
   $span = '<span class="fa-gamepad">';
  } else { // Regular post
    $span = '<span class="fa-eye">';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been reading all the answers, they are usable, but the most simple that you can use to check if the post is standard or custom, you can just go with:

```
is_singular('post') or !is_singular('post')
```

The first expression is for standard post, and the second one is for any custom post.

I hope it can help someone.

Comment: I think there are already a couple of answers for is_singular()

Comment: Hello @Rup, yes it is, but none of the answers are describing how to select non-standard post eg -> !is_singular('post') is the simplest solution.