# to create own conditional tags for business directory in wp

Tags: conditional-content, directory

i want to create conditional tags for the business directory categories as the conditional tags which are provided are for normal categories.which do not work for the business directory categories.can i do ths? if yes, then how?

thanks in advance.

Comment: what the name of the plugin you are using to create the business directory categories?

Answer (score 2):

you can use [has_term](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term) to check if a post as a term which that is what "business directory categories" are (custom taxonomy terms).
something like:

```
if (has_term( $term, $taxonomy, $post_id )){
//do your thing
}
```

if you want to check if you are in a specific term ( like `is_category`) you can use [is_tax](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_tax)

```
if (is_tax( $taxonomy, $term )){
//do stuff
}
```

if you want to check if your object (post) is in a specific term ( like `in_category`) you can use [is_object_in_term()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_object_in_term)

```
if (is_object_in_term( $object_id, $taxonomy, $terms) ){
//do stuff
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure what your "business directory" categories are. Are you using a specific plugin to create this business directory?

Taking a stab in the dark, you've got two options. If these categories are the same categories under the "Posts" taxonomy, then you could use this:

```
is_category('my-business-category');
```

If, however, your using a special plugin that adds its own custom taxonomy (meaning you aren't using the "posts" but you have a "directory" section in WP-admin, and you want to check if that is what the user is looking at, you would have to use something like this:

Put this in your functions.php:

```
function is_post_type($type){
    global $wp_query;
    if($type == get_post_type($wp_query->post->ID)) return true;
    return false;
}
```

and the you can use this to find the custom post type:

```
is_post_type('business_post_type')
```

Which I originally found here:

[If is custom post type](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6731/if-is-custom-post-type/22166#22166)

Hope this helps!

Comment: not sure if that's what she meant and your code wont check for custom taxonomy but for a post type.