# Taxonomy template by post type

Tags: customization, templates, taxonomy, post-type

I have 2 custom post types that share a taxonomy.
The taxonomy template of my taxonomy ( taxonomy-my_tax.php ) will query both custom post types.

Is there a way to have a taxonomy template for each post type ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve. Taxonomy archive templates doesn't work this way.

Comment: I'm trying to get an archive template that list the articles form a taxonomy, from a custom post type

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use one file as a "taxonomy" template, but want to style posts differently by post type, I'd advise using an if statement. I'm not sure how far you're going, but if you're just changing the loop for example, it would look something like this:

[Using this question as reference](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6731/if-is-custom-post-type).

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

                if( 'blue' == get_post_type() ){
                    //some custom file, custom-blue.php
                    get_template_part( 'content', 'blue' );
                elseif ( 'red' == get_post_type() ){
                    //some custom file, custom-red.php
                    get_template_part( 'content', 'red' );
                } else {
                    //the default loop file, content-format.php
                    get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
                }

endwhile; ?>
```

You can write an if statement like this to add classes, wrap certain sections in your template and so on - depends on what you need. In my example, it imagines that you have two custom files, custom-red.php and custom-blue.php and if the post type is neither red or blue, then it defaults to it's regular functionality. Hope that helps!